# How can I set up keyboard shortcuts that launch the Terminal with different styles (per shortcut)?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, macos-sierra

I know that I can set a default style in the Terminal app and simply assign a shortcut to open the Terminal, but I actually want 4 keyboard shortcuts, each opening the Terminal app with a different style.

I'm coming from Windows & PuTTy or XWin-32, for whom I know how to create saved sessions or pass in arguments via custom command-line arguments.

I have no idea how to even get started with this on MacOS X.